# Eclipse ignores failOnMissingWebXml user property

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I created an empty web project using Eclipse Mars and Maven 3.3.3. For now, this project only contains the pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>2.6</version> -->
<!--                <configuration> -->
<!--                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> -->
<!--                </configuration> -->
<!--            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now Eclipse complains about a missing `web.xml` file. From the documentation of the maven-war-plugin one can [set the user property](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml) `failOnMissingWebXml`, so there is no need to further configure this plugin. This works using Maven from the command line, the project is build successfully. But Eclipse still complains about the missing web.xml.

Does anybody know how to get rid of this Maven configuration error in Eclipse by just using this user property?

**Update:** I have another development environment using Eclipse Luna SR1 and Maven 3.2.5 where it does not complain about the missing web.xml in a newly created web project. So I wonder if this error is somehow suppressed by the m2e plugin.

Comment: It's neither a Maven configuration error nor a Eclipse problem you have simply wrong things in your pom file. You need to activate the configuration part which you have commented out.

Comment: But this is exactly what I want to avoid by using the property `failOnMissingWebXml`. If I set it to true or remove it, the command line Maven build fails. With this property set to false, the build succeeds. So everything works, just Eclipse doesn't understand it.

Comment: If the behaviour is wrong create an issue at the m2e project.

Comment: There already is a Bug for this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471622

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing wtp-m2e `1.2.1` from http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/snapshots/mars/ fixes this issue for me.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you!